# Morrowind with Advanced Herbalism: When to harvest which plant

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I've started a new game of morrowind recently, and added the "Advanced Herbalism" Mod. Supposedly, plants I harvest should have a chance to drop seeds if harvested during the right moon phase - I found the almanac that tells me which phases the moons are in, but no information regarding which phases I should be looking for.

Is there any ingame book listing the best moon phases to harvest plants if I want seeds or can someone tell me whether plants *only* drop seeds during those moon phases or whether that merely increases my chances?

Comment: we don't do resource recommendation requests here, but the rest of your question is perfectly fine, so I removed the part asking for an out of game resource.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no answers yet and I've just gotten my first couple seeds, I'll use this space to post what I've found.

I got several seeds of the same plant, after no seeds from that plant before, and none of the other plants I happened to harvest on the same day gave seeds. So I guess it's safe to say that the moon phases DO matter, and plants have different phases to harvest seeds in.

Plant seeds and the moon phases I got them in according to the herbalist's Almanac (will add more as I find them):

violet coprinus spores: both secunda and masser at cressend (sic) moon